# CSS rollover image

Tags: html, css

I would like the top half of this image to display by default, and then use some CSS to make the image shift upward so that the bottom half shows when the mouse hovers over it. Here is the code and what I've tried, but it is not working. Can anyone help me make this code work?

HTML:

```
<div id="next">
  <a href="page2.html"><img src="images/next3.png" alt="next page"></a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#next a:hover{background: url('images/next3.png') 0 -45px;}
```

[image]

EDIT: 
HTML:

```
 <div id="next">

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#next {
      height:40px;
      width:160px;
      background-image:url('images/next3.png');
    }

#next:hover{background-position: 100% 100%;}
```

Comment: Assuming that's the actual button, you can do this with pure CSS (no images in the markup OR in the stylesheet).

Comment: I agree. No need for an image here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `background-position` attribute to achieve this.

CSS

```
div
{
    height:40px;
    width:160px;
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOGtn.png');
}

div:hover
{
    background-position:100% 100%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/zzun9/)

You can also look into [CSS Sprites](http://alistapart.com/article/sprites).

Comment: Would the edit I made above accomplish the same thing? Doesn't seem to be working for some reason when I update my code that way.

Comment: Your code is also working here http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/Jcs3z/. The only difference that i use image that you posted here. may be you trying with different image. So can you make a example here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Just found my problem. I was linking the image incorrectly. Forgot I created a CSS folder.

Comment: Now how do I make it clickable? I still have the link  <a href="page2.html"></a> in it but can't click the image.

Comment: Then you need to add some css for your anchor. Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/zzun9/4/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it as a background in the first place. The `<img>` is covering the background.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the image HTML and just use some CSS like this

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 160px;
    background: transparent url(img.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

a:hover {
    background-position: 0 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you will need to remove your `<img>` tag and consistently use the CSS background attribute for both cases. Also define your height and width width of your `a` tag with CSS too.